# Running an ImageMagick script on ubuntu

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I have perviously installed and used Image Magick on Windows and had it working fine. Now I am trying to get it running and have installed it on my Ubuntu instance.
I verified it works by doing simple "convert" test on a sample image. 
Now I have found this site with useful Unix based scripts. http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php

My question is How do I run one of these scripts.  I copy for example "textcleaner" script onto my home folder `/usr/home`

How do I run the script as per the Usage instruction?

```
USAGE: textcleaner [-r rotate] [-l layout] [-c cropoff] [-g] [-e enhance ] [-f filtersize]
[-o offset] [-u] [-t threshold] [-s sharpamt] [-s saturation] [-a adaptblur] [-T]
[-p padamt] [-b bgcolor] infile outfile
```

when I run command from the same folder as the textcleaner script is stored in as in command "textcleaner" it does nothing ,  just message "command not found"
So this is really a question on how do I register this script if that is the correct way to say it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make the script executable.

```
chmod +x textcleaner
```

Then execute it directly with...

```
./textcleaner [options]
```

If you want to make the script available system wide, just install it to `/usr/local/bin`.

```sh
sudo cp -p ./textcleaner /usr/local/bin/textcleaner
# Or even just
sudo install textcleaner /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Or if you put all the scripts in one folder, then add the path to that folder to your PATH environment variable in you .profile or .bash_profile, that will allow it to be run anywhere. See my Pointers on my home page at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html

Comment: You can also run it from anywhere by the command "bash path2/textcleaner ... argument ... input output" (without the quotes)

Comment: Also, the default shell profile adds the `bin` subdirectory of your home directpry to the path if it exists, so this is a good place to put your own scripts.